# .NET Core Web API Key Authentication - Where to store? Should I cache?

Tags: api-key

I have developed a .NET Core Web API that will use some API Key Authentication. It is not a user facing API and is called by some other applications, so I'd like to have multiple API keys, one for each application.

To handle this I have written the below ApiKeyAttribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ApiKeyAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private const string API_KEY_HEADER = "z-api-key"; //This is the name we are looking in the headers for the value
    private const string DUMMY_KEY = "dummy-key-do-not-use"; //Testing key only REMOVE.

    private List<string> ApiKeyCache = new List<string>();

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var keyHeaderExists = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(API_KEY_HEADER, out var keyHeaderValue);

        if (!keyHeaderExists)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult($"No api key was provided. Please provide a key in the '{API_KEY_HEADER}' header.");
            return;
        }

        //TODO: Some proper api key validation once we have agreed how best to do it...
        if (!ApiKeyCache.Contains(keyHeaderValue))
        {
            //Do the checks in the database/key vault secrets or where ever it maybe... then add it to the cache if its valid.
        }

        if (keyHeaderValue != DUMMY_KEY)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult($"The provided api key is not authorised.");
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

This works as I'd expect, however I am after some advice on the below.

1. Where is the best place to store multiple keys? Database? Key Vault? App Config?
2. Should I cache authorised keys to minimise database/keyvault calls and ensure optimal performance?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to store your config key in App config.

But if you want to store in database then you must first decrypt to base64 and store in data. but this method may take some more lines of code to decrypt and encrypt then code